# Android SQLite database contains only null values

Tags: android, arrays, database, sqlite, null

I am trying to insert the values from an array into SQLite database.
The problem is that the function can insert only `null` values even though the array does not contain such values.

The function for insert :

```
public void addArrayEntry(String [] response){
    try {
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
        ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
        //System.out.println(response.length);
        for (int i=1; i<response.length; i++){
            values.put(temperature,response[i]);
            db.insert(tableStatistics,null,values);
        }

        db.close();
    }

    catch (Exception e){
        Log.e("Error in insert", e.toString());
    }

}

String createTable = "CREATE TABLE statistics ( " +
            "id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, " +
            "temperature REAL, "+
            "light INTEGER, "+
            "humidity INTEGER)";
```

Array values :

```
05-08 14:24:21.405 10720-10720/org.security.andreiism.iotsecurity I/System.out﹕ 23.798828125
05-08 14:24:21.405 10720-10720/org.security.andreiism.iotsecurity I/System.out﹕ 744
05-08 14:24:21.405 10720-10720/org.security.andreiism.iotsecurity I/System.out﹕ 424
```

Comment: here it looks fine - maybe problem is elsewhere? or try debug to find what exactly is given to `db.insert` in `values`

Comment: I changed the for sequence to start from 0 and the type of the "temperature" field to "TEXT" and the output is the same.

Comment: Try moving `ContentValues values = new ContentValues();` into the `for` loop

Answer (score 0):

write your `db.insert` outside of the for loop. So all the `values` get only inserted once. What you do is inserting values at the first time with the value lets say 1. On the second time of the insert you insert 1 and 2. On the third time you insert 1, 2 and 3. Now your table will look like this:

```
id| temperature
1 |1
2 |1
3 |2
4 |1
5 |2
6 |3
```

this is because you defined `values` outside of the `for` loop and add values to it like to an `ArrayList`. But this won't get deleted till the next running trough the loop. So the new value will just be added to the `values` before, and all values together will be added to the list.

So your method should look like this:

```
public void addArrayEntry(String [] response){
    try {
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
        ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
        //System.out.println(response.length);
        for (int i=1; i<response.length; i++){
            values.put(temperature,response[i]);

        }
        db.insert(tableStatistics,null,values);
        db.close();
    }

    catch (Exception e){
        Log.e("Error in insert", e.toString());
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try with below changes...

```
public void addArrayEntry(String [] response){
try {
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
    ContentValues values = new ContentValues();

    //System.out.println(response.length);
    for (int i=0; i<response.length; i++) {
        values.put(temperature,response[i]);            
    }

    db.insert(tableStatistics,null,values);
    db.close();
}

catch (Exception e){
    Log.e("Error in insert", e.toString());
}

}

String createTable = "CREATE TABLE statistics ( " +
        "id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, " +
        "temperature REAL, "+
        "light INTEGER, "+
        "humidity INTEGER)";
```

Comment: I tried with the replaced function, but the output is the same.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you all for the help. I finally succeded to insert the required values using the function :

```
public void addArrayEntry(String [] response) {
    try {
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();

        ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
        values.put(temperature, response[1]);
        values.put(light, response[2]);
        values.put(humidity, response[3]);
        db.insert(tableStatistics, null, values);
        db.close();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.e("Error in insert", e.toString());
    }
}
```